# Cannot find any provider supporting RSA/None/OAEPWITHSHA-256ANDMGF1PADDING

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, cryptography, sha

I encountered a strange issue while encrypting with RSA in `javax.crypto`.

I am using `RSA/None/OAEPWITHSHA-256ANDMGF1PADDING` mode as follow...

```java
Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("RSA/None/OAEPWITHSHA-256ANDMGF1PADDING");
```

...and it is working correctly in my spring boot project.

But when I call the same function via `main(String[] args)` in the same project, I am getting the issue:

```
Cannot find any provider supporting RSA/None/OAEPWITHSHA-256ANDMGF1PADDING
```

Again: if I use `RSA/ECB/OAEPWITHSHA-256ANDMGF1PADDING` I get the correct output! (I don't want to use ECB as I know it has no use in the RSA algorithm).

Also, in my another spring boot project, I am getting the same above issue (this time not only `main(String[] args)` but in the Spring Boot project itself as well).

Could anybody help me with this?

Comment: I'm really not sure what t is about the close reasons provided, they don't make **any sense at all** to me. Perfectly answerable.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Basically the ECB in `"RSA/ECB/OAEPWITHSHA-256ANDMGF1PADDING"` as provided by the `"SunJCE"` provider is a misnomer. It probably has been copied from the block cipher modes in the old Java versions. It does **not** allow multiple blocks to be encrypted, which is what you would expect from ECB **mode**. In other words, it is completely identical to `"RSA/None/OAEPWITHSHA-256ANDMGF1PADDING"` - but that algorithm name is generally not accepted with Java SE.

The reason why it doesn't fail in your Spring Boot project is that it likely includes the Bouncy Castle provider (or another provider that registers the algorithm name with `none` inside of it). Bouncy Castle is however a **software only** provider, that has had side channel protection issues. Generally you should prefer the implementation within the `"SunJCE"`.

Just using `"RSA/ECB/OAEPWITHSHA-256ANDMGF1PADDING"` without explicitly specifying the provider is the best way forward.

---

[EDIT] I strongly suggest to set the SHA-256 hash to be used for the label and MGF1 explicitly using `OAEPParameterSpec` and `MGF1ParameterSpec`. Unfortunately Java may default to SHA-1 and using identical hash functions all over is the most compatible option.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Yes, when I print providers via my first Spring Boot project, it shows `BC`. But when I print from main or from another Spring project, it doesn't show up. I don't see anywhere `BC` provider is added in the first Spring boot project. Also, I am using same JDK 11 for both projects. So, it's a strange behavior for me.

Also, I am in a dilemma to use `SunJCE` provider because it has no  `RSA/None/OAEPWITHSHA-256ANDMGF1PADDING` mode. So do you suggest to use `RSA/ECB/OAEPWITHSHA-256ANDMGF1PADDING`  from  `SunJCE` rather than switching to `Bouncy Castle`?

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I'm suggesting.

Comment: I experimented encrypting  data with a public key using  `RSA/ECB/OAEPWITHSHA-256ANDMGF1PADDING`  mode and try decrypting with corresponding private key using `RSA/None/OAEPWITHSHA-256ANDMGF1PADDING`. But I got the error:
`org.bouncycastle.jcajce.provider.util.BadBlockException: unable to decrypt block`.

If they are identical, shouldn't it work? Sorry for my ignorance, as I am very new to cryptography.

P.S.: I am getting correct decryption if I use the same mode  in both encryption and decryption using same key pairs and data.

Comment: That's weird. The only thing I can come up with is that a different hash is used for the label and MGF1 function. Try and set both explicitly using [`OAEPParameterSpec`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/crypto/spec/OAEPParameterSpec.html) and [`MGF1ParameterSpec`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/security/spec/MGF1ParameterSpec.html)

Comment: we got same issue while playstore app signing in that case what will be solution? for below command.  $ java -jar pepk.jar --keystore=foo.keystore --alias=foo --output=encrypted_private_key_path --rsa-aes-encryption --encryption-key-path=/path/to/encryption_public_key.pem

Answer (score 0):

When I faced this issue, I was able to resolve it by specifying the provider likeso
`Security.addProvider(new org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.BouncyCastleProvider())`. So it seems that we need to use the overloaded consutructor

`Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("RSA/None/OAEPWITHSHA-256ANDMGF1PADDING", provider);`

Comment: As already commented in Maarten Bodewes answer (https://stackoverflow.com/a/63442519/8166854) you can run the algorithm without any 3rd party libraries like Bouncy Castle.